# JS validation on MVC form

Tags: javascript, php

Im using a MVC platform in php.

The MVC takes database tabloes and displays them . It also has options to create new entries.

When the 'create new' button is clicked , a form is generated based on the current page/table being viewed by the user.

How would I put validation into this so that the form cannot be submited if a fiedl is empty.

If this were a nomral HTML page , I would know how to do validation , but because its an MVC , the forms are generated for each table , so it makes validation a bit trickier .

Thanks

If there is any ifo I have missed , tell me.

```
<?

    $class_obj=$_REQUEST['class_obj'];

    echo "<p class='p1'>Create new ".$class_obj."</p>";
    if (isset($_REQUEST['post_create']))
    {
        post_create_message($_REQUEST['post_create'],$class_obj);
    }


    echo "<table class=table1><form id=form_create action=".$current_file_name."?here=".$here."&mode=confirm_create&class_obj=".$class_obj." method=post>";

    $w_columns = MyActiveRecord::Columns($class_obj);
    foreach($w_columns as $wcolumns_key => $wcolumns_value)
    {
        if ($wcolumns_key != "id")
        {
            //if($wcolumns_key == "date")
            if(MyActiveRecord::GetType($class_obj,$wcolumns_key) == 'date')
            {
                echo "<tr><td>".$wcolumns_key."<td><input type=text id='input_".$wcolumns_key."' name='input_".$wcolumns_key."' value=''>";
                echo "<td><input type=button value='Set Date' onclick=displayDatePicker('input_".$wcolumns_key."',false,'ymd','-'); >";

                //echo "<tr id='arow'><td>".$wcolumns_key."<td><input type=text id='input_".$wcolumns_key."' name='input_".$wcolumns_key."' value='' datepicker='true' datepicker_format='DD/MM/YYYY'>";
                //echo "<tr><td>".$wcolumns_key."<td><input type=text id='input_".$wcolumns_key."' name='input_".$wcolumns_key."' value='' datepicker='true' datepicker_format='DD/MM/YYYY'><td><div id='aaa'>&nbsp;</div><script>var b = new free_date_picker('b', 'aaa', 'input_".$wcolumns_key."', 1, true, 'en');</script>";




            }
            else
            {

                echo "<tr><td>".$wcolumns_key."<td><input type=text id='input_".$wcolumns_key."' name='input_".$wcolumns_key."' value=''>";
                if (strlen($wcolumns_key)> 2 && !(strpos($wcolumns_key,"_id")===false))
                {
                    //$related_class = substr($wcolumns_key, 0, -3);
                    $related_class = find_relatedclass($wcolumns_key,$foreign_keys);
                    echo "<td><select id='select_".$wcolumns_key."' onChange=javascript:change_obj('".$wcolumns_key."') ><option></option>";

                    foreach ($obj_class = MyActiveRecord::FindBySql($related_class, 'SELECT * FROM '.$related_class.' WHERE id > -1 ORDER BY referred_as') as $obj_attribute => $obj_attr_value)
                    {
                    // echo "<option>".$obj_attribute." - ".$obj_attr_value->referred_as;    // it works, but...

                        echo "<option value='".$obj_attr_value->id."'>".$obj_attr_value->id." - ".$obj_attr_value->referred_as;

                    //echo "(".$wcolumns_key.")";

                         if (strlen($wcolumns_key)> 2 && !(strpos($wcolumns_key,"_id")===false))
                        {
                            // $related_superclass = substr($wcolumns_key, 0, -3);
                            $related_superclass = find_relatedclass($wcolumns_key,$foreign_keys);
                            foreach ($super_obj = MyActiveRecord::Columns($related_superclass) as $super_obj_attribute => $super_obj_value)
                            {
                                if (strlen($super_obj_attribute)> 2 && !(strpos($super_obj_attribute,"_id")===false))
                                {
                                    //$related_supersuperclass = substr($super_obj_attribute, 0, -3);
                                    $related_supersuperclass = find_relatedclass($super_obj_attribute,$foreign_keys);

                                    //$related_superobj = $obj_attr_value->find_parent($related_supersuperclass)->referred_as;
                                    $related_superobj = $obj_attr_value->find_parent($related_supersuperclass,$super_obj_attribute)->referred_as;
                                    //echo "<td>".$obj_value->$obj_attribute.". ".$obj_value->find_parent($related_class,$obj_attribute)->referred_as;


                                    echo " (".$related_superobj.")";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select >";
                }

            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($join_tables as $jt_key => $jt_value)
    {
        $pos = strpos($jt_value,$here);
        if($pos === false) {
                        // string needle NOT found in haystack
        }
        else {      // string needle found in haystack

            $there = str_replace("_","",$jt_value);
            $there = str_replace($here,"",$there);

            include "view_displayjt.php";
        }
    }


    echo "<tr><td><td><input type=button value='Create new ".$here."' onClick=javascript:confirm_create('form_create');><td><input type=reset >";
    echo "</table></form>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in simple html,you could provide the javascript code within the view file in the directory `"Views/"`

Comment: Okay , but what about the different forms . I have updated my post and included the view_create.php page which generates the form.  The MVC im using is this one: http://homepages.feis.herts.ac.uk/~comqvv/vf1/